# AWS EC2 deleted but still shows current usage

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-instance-store

I am using AWS EC2 free tier now.

I deleted EC2 instances but my billing dashboard shows current usage space is `11 GB-MO`.

[image]

Here is my billing dashboard image.

[image]

And here is EC2 dashboard.

[image]

Can any one help me how to clean instance?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dashboard shows that you’ve got **2 EBS Volumes** and **1 Elastic IP address** - these are both chargeable resources. If you don’t need them delete them. *Security groups* and *Key pairs* are free, you don’t have to remove them.

Also check out other *Regions* - perhaps you’ve created some resources there as well?

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I think 2 EBS Volumns got usage size.